# Git submodule inside another external submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to set up on (my .dotfile repository)[https://github.com/mike-fam/.dotfiles]. I want to install Oh-my-zsh when I clone this repository, so I added it as a submodule to my directory by running

```
git submodule add git@github.com:ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh.git .oh-my-zsh
git submodule absorbgitdirs .oh-my-zsh
```

However, I also have some Oh-my-zsh custom plugins that should be in the `custom/plugins` directory of the Oh-my-zsh directory, and I want to add it as a **nested** submodule in Oh-my-zsh. This directory is ignored by Oh-my-zsh, so it should not affect the containing repository.

```
git submodule add git@github.com:jeffreytse/zsh-vi-mode.git .oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/zsh-vi-mode
```

But I get the error:

```
fatal: Pathspec '.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/zsh-vi-mode' is in submodule '.oh-my-zsh'
```

How should I go about this?

Thanks everyone